# Rename multiple names and emails in a single pass of git-filter-branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

Is it possible to mass-rename 2 or more email addresses with a single pass of `git filter-branch`?

I tried adapting the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870367/492336) by just duplicating the `if..fi clause`:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old Name 1>" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name 1>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name 1>";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email 1>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email 1>";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old Name 2>" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name 2>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name 2>";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email 2>";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email 2>";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

But it gave me errors during the filter-branch that looked like this:

```
error: duplicate parent bc8f9924c33558a275b8f694969529cf56232c80 ignored
```

And then the branch history was all tangled up:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want just one `git commit-tree` command, after setting all the environment variables as desired.  For instance, your commit filter might read something like this:

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old Name 1>" ]; then
        GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name 1>";
        GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name 1>";
        GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email 1>";
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email 1>";
    fi;
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old Name 2>" ]; then
        GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name 2>";
        GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name 2>";
        GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email 2>";
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email 2>";
    fi;
    git commit-tree "$@"
    '
```

(although if the number of name changes to make gets higher I'd probably run through a mapping file instead of a long series of easy-to-typo `if ... then`s, and it might make more sense to map author and committer separately).

Remember that `filter-branch` simply *copies* all the commits you tell it to copy (by using `git commit-tree` to make the new copy), while building a map of <old-sha1,new-sha1> pairs.  This is why making two commits is not good: one existing (old) SHA-1 now has to map to two new copies, which is simply not allowed in terms of what `filter-branch` does with the commit graph.  (Multiple old SHA-1s can map to a single new SHA-1, if you choose to *omit* some commits during the copying process.  That is, the new graph can be bijective or surjective, but filter-branch doesn't really believe in injective, as it's going to try to map the old references to the new graph.)